# How to hide categories in Pandas xlsxwriter Chart

Tags: python, pandas, charts, xlsxwriter

I want to show a chart on Pnadas+xlsxwriter and after that hide some categories(or series).
The main idea why it needs - to provide to user a full functionality document. If he wants he can show it again and try to analyze full data.

So, in current time I have follow

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
   workbook = writer.book

   ...

    chart.add_series({
            'name':       series_descript + ' ' + series_key +' ' + ' '.join(np.unique(df[i][series_key])),
            'categories': [data_sheet, tables_ypos_df[i][0]+1, col_x, tables_ypos_df[i][1], col_x],
            'values':     [data_sheet, tables_ypos_df[i][0]+1, col_y, tables_ypos_df[i][1], col_y],
            'marker':     {'type': 'circle', 'size': 4},
        })

    chart.set_x_axis({'name': x_axis})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name': y_axis, 'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})
    chart.set_title({'name': titile, 'name_font':{'name':'Calibri(Body)','size':14}})
    writer.sheets[location_sheet].insert_chart(chart_shift_x, chart, {'x_scale': 2, 'y_scale': 1.75} )`
```

How I can make the same like in picture but by Pandas + xlsxwriter features ?

[image]

I understand that I can apply some filters to the table that the source for this chart but maybe I either have some ability to make like this by Pandas + xlsxwriter features ?

Thanks in advance

I'm expecting to automate by pandas + xlsxwriter hiding categories and series like in the pucture.
In the picture hiding is making by manually, by user. I want to avoid this.

Comment: Unfortunately that feature isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sed news. Well, will try to make this by table autofilters.